# How to write SQL query to ignore duplicate row with null value

Tags: sql

My View shows Duplicate row which i don't want.

I am geting

```
1, YM
1, NULL
2, YM
2, NULL
```

With below Code

```
SELECT 
   dbo.Store.SID,
   CASE WHEN dbo.Store.SID <> dbo.FileStore.SID THEN NULL 
        WHEN dbo.FileStore.MailSent = 'M' THEN 'YM' 
        WHEN dbo.FileStore.SID = dbo.Store.SID AND dbo.FileStore.FileType = 1 THEN 'Y' 
   ELSE NULL END AS FM 
FROM 
dbo.STORE 
    INNER JOIN dbo.FileStore ON dbo.Store.SID = dbo.FileStore.SID
```

I am looking for

```
1 YM
2 YM
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to want filtering.  If I understand correctly:

```
SELECT s.SID,
       (CASE WHEN fs.MailSent = 'M' THEN 'YM'
             WHEN fs.FileType = 1 THEN 'Y' 
        END) AS FM
FROM dbo.STORE s INNER JOIN
     dbo.FileStore fs
     ON s.SID = fs.SID
WHERE fs.MailSent = 'M' OR fs.FileType = 1;
```

There is no reason to repeat the `JOIN` conditions in the `CASE` expression.  You know they are true because of the `JOIN`.

Comment: This is my first post, sorry if i am not clear. I want All Records from Table Store, if there is no record in FileStore then FM should come with null Value

Comment: i have 10 records in Store Like SID = 1 to 10 and 6 in FileStore, like SID= 1,1,2,2,3,3 FileType = 1,2,1,3,1,5 MailSent = M,NULL,NULL,NULL,M (There is no records for SID 4 to 10 in FileStore) I want result 10 Rows

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
dbo.Store.SID
,CASE 
   WHEN dbo.Store.SID <> dbo.FileStore.SID THEN NULL --will never happen since it's an inner join
   WHEN dbo.FileStore.MailSent = 'M' THEN 'YM' 
   WHEN dbo.FileStore.SID = dbo.Store.SID --will happen always since it's an inner join
     AND dbo.FileStore.FileType = 1 THEN 'Y' 
   ELSE NULL -- this is the cause for Null, you have FileStore.MailSent <> 'M'
 END AS FM
FROM dbo.STORE 
INNER JOIN dbo.FileStore
     ON dbo.Store.SID = dbo.FileStore.SID
```

Comment: Yes I have FileStore.MailSent <> 'M' and also FileType>1, I want Y, YM if File Type =1 Else NULL. FileStore having only records whose file is inserted, I want NULL also if there is no SID Match in filestore

Comment: Well, that is not clear from your question I'm afraid. In that case you'll need to use LEFT JOIN. If you'll correct your question I'll try to adjust the solution to it